# Qt Designer Menu Format Similar to 3D Slicer

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

I need to re-create a section of a GUI used in 3D Slicer in Qt Designer, but I can't exactly pin down what I need to use to make this:

[image]

which turns into:

[image]

I think that it's a drop-down menu that holds or acts as a container. This looks similar to a combo box, however the combo box cannot contain selection buttons that I would need in my application (at least to my knowledge). I think that it could possibly utilize a Tree Widget or List Widget, but I've looked through the Qt Design documentation and it doesn't mention anything similar, other than a combo box.

Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: Could this also be related to a ctk collapsible button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt this would be called a `ToolBox`.
It has the behavior that you're looking for.
In there you can place a TreeView to get the same look.

To be more specific: [QToolBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qtoolbox.html)

Comment: I've tried that but I cannot get it to collapse - it still displays the content

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. In actuality it turned out to be a CTK collapsible button but without that a toolbox would work just fine.